# git fatal error after deleting repo

Tags: git, github

This is not similar to posted questions, as I've done my research.

I'm trying to pull a new repo created on github and get this error message:

```
$ git pull https://github.com/{my repo}.git
From https://github.com/{my repo}
 * branch            HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

I've tried this:

```
$ git merge origin/master --allow-unrelated-histories
merge: origin/master - not something we can merge
```

also this:

```
$ git pull --allow-unrelated-histories origin master
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/{my user name}/20170802.git/' not found
```

and this:

```
$ git fetch
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/{my uer name}/20170802.git/' not found
```

This happens after I've removed the repo which didn't let me push a movie file (which is bigger than 50mb). When github didn't allow me to upload the file: I reset the stage, and deleted the movie file and pasted a new one in my project folder on my computer, and tried to push again, but gitbash kept showing I was trying to push the old movie file.
I'm using gitbash for windows 10.

Comment: Are you trying to clone or pull? You also seem to be missing the username in your URL in the first code snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using the git `clone` command?
Like so:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/{my repo}.git
```

This [command](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Getting-a-Git-Repository) will create a local copy of the remote git repository you specify in the directory git bash is currently on.

You mention pulling a "new repo" and you say you have previously "deleted the repo", as you were having trouble pushing some content. Thus, it seems likely that this repository needs to be cloned to a local directory again. This is the reason why the error tells you that the repository has not been found, because it's not physically present in your local environment anymore.

If you're trying to bring the repository to your computer for the first time (or if it's not presently there anymore), then you must use the git `clone` command.

After you have cloned it, your repository branches will already be up to date with origin's latest commits.

Later on, when changes have occured in origin/{branch_name}, there you use `git fetch` and `git pull` to get your local branches up to date.

Comment: Thank you  TW80000 and 0xDEFACED for clearing this up. I was out of my head because of the errors I got and made a rookie's mistake for confusing the 2 projects with similar names, one is for work and one is personal.

Comment: No prob! Glad to help :)